# Nvidia drivers not working on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on my 2021 Acer Nitro 5.
The problem is that Nvidia gpu isn't working.

I installed the drivers through the "additional drivers" panel and I choose a version that was not Nouveau (Actually i tried all versions including open kernel and server from 475 through 525); actually I'm running `nvidia-driver-525 (proprietary)`

If I open nvidia-smi I get the following error `NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.` .

Same for nvidia-settings: `ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded`

The strange thing is that I had Ubuntu 22.04 installed on another drive and Nvidia was working perfcectly, but now when I reinstalled it it's not working.

I have disabled Secure Boot too and I tried reinstalling with latest kernel headers; I have also already checked all solutions but didn't work for me.

The GPU is an GTX 1650 Ti Mobile.
CPU: i5-10300H

Here's the [nvidia-bug-report file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rIfsRIQeSc0iItHy3eWFLczdq2THnMy-/view?usp=share_link)

Thanks for the help in advance

Output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics] (rev 05)
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics]
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile]
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
```

Output of `sudo modprobe nvidia`:

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:838 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='off'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'off': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

Output of `grep nvidia /lib/modprobe.d/*`:

```
/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf:# This file was generated by nvidia-prime
/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf:blacklist nvidia
/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf:blacklist nvidia-drm
/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf:blacklist nvidia-modeset
/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf:alias nvidia off
/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf:alias nvidia-drm off
/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf:alias nvidia-modeset off
/lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-runtimepm.conf:options nvidia "NVreg_DynamicPowerManagement=0x02"
```

Ouput of `grep nvidia /etc/modprobe.d/*`:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer.conf:blacklist nvidiafb
/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers-kms.conf:# This file was generated by nvidia-driver-525
/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers-kms.conf:options nvidia-drm modeset=1
```

Output of `cat /etc/default/grub`:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="5"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: `nvidia` isn't loaded. What does it say in `sudo dmesg | grep nvidia`

Comment: @Pilot6 done, thanks!

Comment: @Pilot6 output is: 
`[    3.015352] audit: type=1400 audit(1675704909.064:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=497 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.015356] audit: type=1400 audit(1675704909.064:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=497 comm="apparmor_parser" `

Comment: Also output of `sudo modprobe nvidia` and `cat /etc/default/grub`

Comment: Please add output of `grep nvidia /etc/modprobe.d/*`

Comment: Also `grep nvidia /lib/modprobe.d/*`

Comment: Do I add them as code tags or as external files? Thanks @Pilot6

Comment: Add them like you do now. But first give output of the last grep commands. We are close to a solution. And there is no need to type EDIT every time.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Pilot6

Comment: Before you remove it, you could check `dpkg -S /lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf` to see where it came from.

Comment: Sorry, saw this to late

Comment: If it appears again, then you know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `nvidia` module blacklisted in `/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf`.

This file is not used now and was probably added by some software installed from a PPA.

Remove this file by

```
sudo rm /lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf
```

and reboot.

Comment: Thanks a lot, can't figure out what happened as I think I did the same procedure as the last time I installed

Comment: That file shouldn't exist. You did something wrong.

Comment: Is it possible Nouveau blacklists nvidia kernel module?

Comment: No. `nouveau` doesn't blacklist anything.

Comment: Maybe you disabled `nvidia` by `nvidia-prime` if you selected Intel in GUI, or by `prime-select intel`.